# Spring Boot : Failed to parse configuration class

Tags: spring-boot

I am new to spring boot technology.
I have created a very basic application. The idea is to publish a HTML page using spring boot. Tool I am using is STS4 ( version 4.18 ).
I created a html file in src/main/resources in both static and templates. Then I created a normal class LoadRegistrationPage ( annotated with @Component, @Controller @PropertySource )

[LoadRegistrationPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7fZC.png)

Then I created a ConfigClass which is annotated with @Configuration @ComponentScan @PropertySource.

[ConfigClass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2SoK.png)

then finally I have called it from main class UserRegistrationPageApplication

[UserRegistrationPageApplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU9f3.png)

Now When I am running this as SpringBootApplication, it is giving exception "Failed to parse configuration class [application.com.example.UserRegistrationPage.UserRegistrationPageApplication]".

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Jm62.png).

I have tried in many ways but unable to understand what is the issue here.
Can anyone of you please suggest here.

Regards,
Vishal

I tied below stated

1. introduced @component scan in config class.

Comment: Check your exception, the error is caused by `Registrationcode.html` cannot be found. Perhaps there is a typo in the name, I believe from recollection it is case sensitive. Also try to use the path `templates/Registrationcode.html`

Comment: An HTML file doesn't contain properties so it cannot be used as a property source. What were you hoping that `@PropertySource(value = "classpath:Registrationcode.html")` would do?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `@PropertySource` is incorrect.

try

`@PropertySource(value = "classpath:templates/Registrationcode.html")`

instead